# Hartl Rails 9.6.3 exercise. testing strong params admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, railstutorial.org

With this code, the test works as expected. Red when `:admin` is in `params` and green when `:admin` is removed.

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
 log_in_as(@other_user)
 assert_not @other_user.admin?
 patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:             'password',
                                        password_confirmation: 'password',
                                        admin: true }
 assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
end
```

user `params` in users controller

```
private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                 :password_confirmation, :admin )
end
```

If I test using the code below, it is always red and from what I can see allows toggling of `admin`regardless if I do or don't have `:admin` in permitted params.  Why can I change the status of a user from admin to not an admin using this code?

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
 log_in_as(@other_user)
 assert_not @other_user.admin?
 patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:                 'password',
                                        password_confirmation:    'password',
                                        admin:  @other_user.toggle!(:admin) }
 assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that when you do @other_user.toggle!(:admin), this doesn't just return a value; it actually does toggle the admin value.  This is a toggle that happens *within the (test) code*, not through the web, hence why it is not filtered by user_params. What you probably want to test is:

```
admin: !@other_user.admin?
```